# How can I use If-else?

Tags: r

```
W3  W4  W5  W6  W7
9.4 NA  9.2 9.3 9.4
NA  NA  NA  9.1 9.0
NA  7.0 7.1 NA  7.2
```

I have this kind of data and I want to change the NA in every column to FALSE and I want to know what week they enrolled, I mean the meaning of the value in w3 they got enrolled if it is NA they not yet enrolled, so I want to know how many child enrolled in w3, w4, w5, w6, w7. If they enrolled in w3 i want to disregard the next week.

Comment: You can not mix logical (`FALSE`) and numeric (`9.4`) in one column of a dataframe.

Comment: Should I say the value I will make "TRUE", and how??

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: if the total number of children is 1000, I want to know how many children enrolled on w3, w4, w5, w6, w7. Like w3=300, w4=150, w5=100, w6=280 and w7= 170 just like this.

Comment: @ChaiDecena If you have additional information or another example then please edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57621576/edit

Comment: Name  W3 W4 W5 W6 W7
Cha  9.4 NA 9.2 9.3 9.4
Jess  NA NA NA 9.1 9.0
Lyn  NA 7.0 7.1 NA 7.2
Carl  7.6 7.6 NA 7.8 7.8
Wil  NA 8.0 8.1 8.2 8.2
Result:
 W3 W4 W5 W6 W7
 2 2 0 1 0  
Which:
 W3 W4 W5 W6 W7
 Cha Lyn - Jess - 
 Carl Wil - - -

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `NA` with `false` using [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html).

Check this [example](https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/replace_na.html),

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA), y = c("a", NA, "b"), z = list(1:5, NULL, 10:20))
df %>% replace_na(list(x = 0, y = "unknown"))
df %>% mutate(x = replace_na(x, 0))

# NULL are the list-col equivalent of NAs
df %>% replace_na(list(z = list(5)))

df$x %>% replace_na(0)
df$y %>% replace_na("false")
```

or

`library(dplyr)`
`df %>% replace(is.na(.), 'false')`

You can find the sum of NAs in a column: `sum(is.na(df$W3))` 
How many child enrolled in w3: `sum(!is.na(df$W3))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
df <- data.frame(
    colA = rep.int(x = 1, times = 3),
    colB = c(2, NA, 2),
    colC = c(3, NA, NA)
)

df_res <- sapply(X = df, FUN = function(x) {
    ifelse(is.na(x), FALSE, x)
})
df_res
```

Consider that your columns will be of class `numeric`, which means that your `FALSE` statements will be represented as zeros.

```
sapply(df_res, class)
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

***This is problematic as you won't know whether `0` is actual `0` or `FALSE`!***

If you insist on having `"FALSE"` value represented as string you could achieve this in the following manner:

```
vapply(
    X = df,
    FUN = function(x) {
        ifelse(is.na(x), FALSE, as.character(x))
    },
    FUN.VALUE = character(length = 3)
)
```

I

```
# colA colB    colC   
# [1,] "1"  "2"     "3"    
# [2,] "1"  "FALSE" "FALSE"
# [3,] "1"  "2"     "FALSE"
```

This is problematic as you will have to convert your strings to numeric variables to do any calculations on that data frame.

## Recommended approach

If you need not to filter out/in `NA` values make use of the `is.na` function. You can even reverse it and create a convenience function:

```
is.not.na <- Negate(is.na)
is.not.na(c(NA, 1, 2, 3))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```